# how to conditionally render the respond from an api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I want to get input from a user and compare it with the response I am getting from API, and conditionally render the information if it match or just show a sorry message,(the API only contain 1 set of a data object including 4 value) let me know what am I missing.

here is my code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


function Form() {
  const [vatInput, setVatInput] = useState("");
  const [responseVatState, setResponseVatState] = useState("");
  const [responseCountryCodeState, setResponseCountryCodeState] = useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = useState(false);

  const handelVatState = (event) => {
    setVatInput(event.target.value);
  };

  const closeModalHandler = () => {
    setResult(false);
  };

  const onFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios
      .get("Some URL")
      .then((response) => {
        setResponseVatState(response.data.response.data.VATNumber);
        setResponseCountryCodeState(response.data.CountryCode);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  const inputCountryCode = vatInput.substring(0, 2);
  const inputVatCode = vatInput.substring(2);
  if (
    inputCountryCode === responseCountryCodeState &&
    inputVatCode === responseVatState
  ) {
    setResult(true);
  } else {
    setResult(false);
  }

  return (
    <div >
        <h4>VAT Validator</h4>
        <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
          <label className="text-muted">Please Enter A Vat Number:</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="VatInput"
              placeholder="Please Enter A Vat Number"
              onChange={handelVatState}
            />
  
          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Let'Go" />
        </form>

          <label className="text-muted">Result : </label>

          {result ? (
            <div>{vatInput}</div>
          ) : (
          <div clicked={closeModalHandler}>
           <span> Sorry !!! Please Insert corect VAT Number</span>
         </div>    
          )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

and the error is

```
react-dom.development.js:14997 Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

so I get the input from the user and set it with hooks, then with Axios call get my data, then I split the string with

```
 const inputCountryCode = vatInput.substring(0, 2);
  const inputVatCode = vatInput.substring(2);
```

to compare with the input I have, if it's the same then render the data if not  just render the sorry message

Comment: Let me check if I understood the question correctly. Are you asking the user to enter a VAT number, then you are doing the request with axios to validate it? If it was a valid VAT number you say it was, otherwise show a error to the user? If that is the case how does the vat api work? What happens if you give it a invalid order vs a valid order.

Comment: @mellet, yes you got it right. and the API only contain 1 VATNUMBER which is =>BG999999999. so I actually have to compare the user's input with only this number

Comment: Do you have an error or it is simply not yielding the result you expect? What's the problem exactly? You have a couple of issues in your code but we need to start from somewhere.

Comment: @zhulien, updated with the error

Comment: @zhulien, i would be glad if you point out my mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues, the main of which resulting in `Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` is due to an infinite loop of component re-rendering, which you force by setting state directly in the function body.

More specifically, this code:

```
  if (
    inputCountryCode === responseCountryCodeState &&
    inputVatCode === responseVatState
  ) {
    setResult(true);
  } else {
    setResult(false);
  }
```

force react to re-evaluate the component because you're changing its state by using `setResult`. When react starts rendering the new body it yet again encounters `setResult` which results in a new update and re-render which, as you see, leads to a never-ending loop.

Furthermore, you don't need to save the request response to the component state at all, as it is relevant just for the calculation, which is needed only in the form submit handler itself. So, you should ditch the

```
  const [responseVatState, setResponseVatState] = useState("");
  const [responseCountryCodeState, setResponseCountryCodeState] = useState("");
```

state variables altogether. The only state you need except the input value is the validation result.

Also, you have a typo: `setResponseVatState(response.data.response.data.VATNumber);` should be `setResponseVatState(response.data.VATNumber);`.

Try this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Form() {
   const [vatValue, setVatValue] = useState("");
   const [isVatValid, setIsVatValid] = useState(false);

   const handelVatState = (event) => {
      setVatValue(event.target.value);
   };

   const closeModalHandler = () => {
      setIsVatValid(false);
   };

   const onFormSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      axios
         .get("[URL]")
         .then((response) => {
            const inputCountryCode = vatValue.substring(0, 2);
            const inputVatCode = vatValue.substring(2);

            const { VATNumber, CountryCode } = response.data;

            if (inputCountryCode === CountryCode && inputVatCode === VATNumber) {
               setIsVatValid(true);
            } 
            else {
               setIsVatValid(false);
            }
         })
         .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
         });
   };

   return (
      <div >
         <h4>VAT Validator</h4>
         <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
            <label className="text-muted">Please Enter A Vat Number:</label>
            <input
               type="text"
               name="VatInput"
               placeholder="Please Enter A Vat Number"
               onChange={handelVatState}
            />

            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Let'Go" />
         </form>

         <label className="text-muted">Result : </label>

         {isVatValid ? (
            <div>{vatValue}</div>
         ) : (
               <div clicked={closeModalHandler}>
                  <span> Sorry !!! Please Insert corect VAT Number</span>
               </div>
            )}
      </div>
   );
}

export default Form;
```

Also, I suppose `<div clicked={closeModalHandler}>` should be `<div onClick={closeModalHandler}>`?

---

### **EDIT:**

Here is your solution after comments:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Form() {
   const [vatValue, setVatValue] = useState("");
   const [isVatValid, setIsVatValid] = useState(null);

   const handelVatState = (event) => {
      setVatValue(event.target.value);
   };

   const closeModalHandler = () => {
      setIsVatValid(null);
   };

   const onFormSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      axios
         .get("https://vat.erply.com/numbers?vatNumber=BG999999999")
         .then((response) => {
            const inputCountryCode = vatValue.substring(0, 2);
            const inputVatCode = vatValue.substring(2);

            const { VATNumber, CountryCode } = response.data;

            if (inputCountryCode === CountryCode && inputVatCode === VATNumber) {
               setIsVatValid(true);
            }
            else {
               setIsVatValid(false);
            }
         })
         .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
         });
   };

   const getResultRepresentation = () => {
      if (isVatValid === null) {
         return null;
      }

      if (isVatValid) {
         return (
            <>
               <label className="text-muted">Result: </label>
               <div>{vatValue}</div>
            </>
         );
      }
      else {
         return (
            <div onClick={closeModalHandler}>
               <span> Sorry !!! Please Insert corect VAT Number</span>
            </div>
         );
      }
   }

   return (
      <div >
         <h4>VAT Validator</h4>
         <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
            <label className="text-muted">Please Enter A Vat Number:</label>
            <input
               type="text"
               name="VatInput"
               placeholder="Please Enter A Vat Number"
               value={vatValue} // <= missing
               onChange={handelVatState}
            />

            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Let'Go" />
         </form>
         {getResultRepresentation()}
      </div>
   );
}

export default Form;
```

And [here is a CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-hooks-crw1m?file=/src/Form.js) to test it out.

Comment: thanks, you are right about the typos, I tried your solution but it is not working too, did you try it yourself? because when I run the code first thing I see is the SORRy message. and it's not going away. The idea was to see the message after submitting the form if it's a wrong VatNumber, also the closeModalHandler should head to the start point so the user can submit again

Comment: @Harry9345 Of course you see the 'Sorry' message, that's the logic you have used in your code. Check out the condition you have given in your post. Also, it would be a good idea to post a codesandbox with your actual code so people trying to help you shouldn't create a whole project of their own as to test your code.

Comment: alos can you explain why you use this line =>   
const { VATNumber, CountryCode } = response.data .
(it doestn efect the result while I comment it out)

Comment: @Harry9345 Sorry, it is an unused artifact. Basically, `const { VATNumber, CountryCode } = response.data;` and `response.data.CountryCode`, `inputVatCode === response.data.VATNumber` resolve to the same thing, so you can use either and remove the other. `const { VATNumber, CountryCode } = response.data;` basically extracts the `VATNumber` and `CountryCode` variables from the `response.data` and lets you write `inputCountryCode === CountryCode` instead of `inputCountryCode === response.data.CountryCode`. Just delete the line, I've forgot to remove it when migrating the code.

Comment: @Harry9345 Yes, why not.